# How to deploy an html website without a solution/project file

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm running TFS 2012 with a build to deploy an asp.net application but now I'm trying to create a build to deploy an html site, that's our html mockups folder.  The developer is using eclipse and is able to check in his changes to TFS. It's simply a number of html pages that we want to publish to the QA server on check in.

When setting the build, I have to enter the "Items to build" but I don't have a solution/project to build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How would you deploy it manually?  If it's a simple file copy you can customize your build workflow to do that.  Alternatively, you could create a MSBuild file (.build) that did it, check the build script in, and point to that for your Items To Build.

Comment: Yes, usually just copy the html files to the QA IIS site. I was looking for something out of the box similar to how TFS handles a .net app.

Comment: The more "proper" approach, is to create a WebDeploy package and deploy that.  You would have to create a Web Application Project in Visual Studio to support that however.